# Website Cleaned from malware but still random url getting generated

Tags: wordpress, security, web

I own a website which got affected with malware 6 months back. I have removed every kind of malware and backdoor from site. But still I can see some random URLs and keywords are getting generated.

E.g. `Abc.com/acyov/` `abc.com/cere/`

These kind of URL are getting generated. I don’t have such directories in website.

Please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify what you mean by "getting generated". Generated by whom and visible where?

Comment: That means your website is not clean yet!

Comment: Pease check your directories again, maybe some malware is still present...

Comment: I have cleaned the storage and set it up again. Checked with wordfence and other plugins. Also clonned the website and no link getting generated to cloned site

Comment: Please answer **my question**: Please clarify what you mean by "getting generated". From where are the "keywords" are generated and where do the keywords shows up?